# Mongodb group geolocation if within X meters

Tags: mongodb

So I am trying to group X points if they overlap by X meters say 5 meters.
I am wondering can MongoDB do this.

My current query is not smart at all

```
[{$project: {
          'location': 1,
          'day': {
            '$dayOfMonth': '$updatedAt'
          },
          'month': {
            '$month': '$updatedAt'
          },
          'year': {
            '$year': '$updatedAt'
          }
        }}, {$match: {
          'year': 2022
        }}, {$group: {
          '_id': '$location.coordinates',
          'count': {
            '$sum': 1
          }
        }}, {$project: {
          '_id': 0,
          'count': 1,
          'location.coordinates': {
            '$map': {
              'input': '$_id',
              'in': {
                '$toString': '$$this'
              }
            }
          }
        }}, {$sort: {
          count: -1
        }}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if they overlap by X meters"? Overlap by what? Each point with each point? Maybe you are looking for a buffer like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilLvQ.png) Then you would suggest external library like [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/docs/#buffer)

Comment: So we have a polygon of a suburb, everything inside that suburb needs to be counted and a total count.